# How to return temporary table from a PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to use a PostgreSQL database as a simple job queue for running some simulations. It's been a while since I've written SQL, and despite my best efforts (using ChatGPT, googling the myriad error messages, reading the documentation), I've been unable to figure this one out.

When running this function, I keep getting `Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. malformed array literal: "1"`

I think that's because when it returns, for some reason it's returning just the `job_id` column.

I'm using the following schema:

## runner

```sql
CREATE TABLE runner (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT clock_timestamp() NOT NULL,
    last_seen_at timestamp with time zone,
    alias character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    hostname character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE runner_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE runner_id_seq OWNED BY runner.id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY runner ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('runner_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY runner ADD CONSTRAINT runner_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

## job

```sql
CREATE TYPE public.job_status AS ENUM (
    'pending',
    'failed',
    'complete',
    'running'
);
CREATE TABLE job (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT clock_timestamp() NOT NULL,
    completed_at timestamp with time zone,
    status public.job_status DEFAULT 'pending'::public.job_status NOT NULL,
    specification jsonb NOT NULL,
    upstream_manifest integer,
    completed_by integer,
    attempted_by integer
);

CREATE SEQUENCE job_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE job_id_seq OWNED BY job.id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY job ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('job_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY job
    ADD CONSTRAINT job_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY job
    ADD CONSTRAINT job_attempted_by_fkey FOREIGN KEY (attempted_by) REFERENCES runner(id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY job
    ADD CONSTRAINT job_completed_by_fkey FOREIGN KEY (completed_by) REFERENCES runner(id);
```

## Seeding the tables

```
INSERT INTO runner (alias, hostname) VALUES ('test01', 'test-host');

INSERT INTO job (specification) VALUES ('{"spec": true}'::jsonb);
```

## The request_jobs function

```sql
-- 1. Get runner ID by alias
-- 2. Update runner last seen time (trigger?)
-- 3. Select 'pending' total_jobs limit total_jobs
-- 4. Set the foreign key of the runner who's attempting this job
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.request_jobs(runner_alias text, total_jobs integer)
RETURNS TABLE(job_id integer, specification json) AS $$
DECLARE
    runner_id integer;
    selected_jobs job[];
BEGIN
    -- Start a transaction
    BEGIN
        -- Retrieve the runner_id based on the runner_alias
        SELECT id INTO runner_id FROM runner WHERE alias = runner_alias;

        -- Select the first total_jobs pending jobs to assign them to the runner
        SELECT j.id as job_id, j.specification
        FROM job AS j
        WHERE status = 'pending'
        LIMIT total_jobs
        FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
        INTO selected_jobs;

        -- Update the selected jobs to set their status to 'running' and assign them to the runner
        UPDATE job
        SET attempted_by = runner_id,
            status = 'running'
        WHERE id IN (SELECT job_id FROM selected_jobs);

        -- Return the selected jobs
        RETURN QUERY SELECT s.job_id, s.specification FROM selected_jobs as s;
    END;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've tried rewriting it with a FOR loop (RETURN NEXT), using RETURNS SETOF job, and various other tweaks, but so far, I haven't been able to crack it.

Comment: The issue is here `... INTO selected_jobs;`. `selected_jobs` is an `array` and you are trying to push `job_id, j.specification` into it.  Not sure why you are doing this, because both `SELECT job_id FROM selected_jobs` and `SELECT s.job_id, s.specification FROM selected_jobs` will fail.  It would be better to do `selected_jobs record;`. See [record](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS).

Comment: I'm trying to select multiple jobs here; if it was record would that work? What if it was TABLE?

Comment: You will need to use combination of [Query Loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) and [Returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) *43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY* `RETURN NEXT` . In the LOOP do the UPDATE and the RETURN  NEXT for each record processed.

Comment: Is there no way to use a temporary table for this?

Comment: 1) Why? 2) An array is not a temporary table, so you are not using one now. 3) Yes you can by doing a `CREATE TEMP TABLE <some_table> AS SELECT  ...` in the function and loading the data into it. There is no real need/point when you can loop over the `SELECT j.id as job_id, j.specification   FROM job AS j ...` and accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Mostly because it feels more "right"? But if there's no way to return said table from this function, there wouldn't be a point.

Comment: FYI, `RETURNS TABLE` is an alias for `RETURNS SETOF <some_type>`. So you are actually returning a set of types not a table. Now every Postgres table has an associated composite type with the same name as the table. So you can do `RETURNS SETOF(TABLE) <some_table_name>`, but you are still returning a type.

Comment: if it's returning a subset of those tables, does that actually work? Like in my example, I'm only returning job_id and specification, which is a subset of all the columns in job, so it's not actually `SETOF job`, right?

Comment: No it is not. `RETURNS TABLE(job_id integer, specification json)` is effectively `RETURN SETOF record` with components of `record` named and assigned types. Read [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) and  [plpgsql return next/query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by using a temporary table approach:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.request_jobs(runner_alias text, total_jobs integer)
RETURNS TABLE(job_id integer, specification json) AS $$
DECLARE
    runner_id integer;
BEGIN
    -- Start a transaction
    BEGIN
        -- Retrieve the runner_id based on the runner_alias
        SELECT id INTO runner_id FROM api.runner WHERE alias = runner_alias;

        -- Create a temporary table to insert the data into
        
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE selected_jobs (job_id integer, specification json)
        ON COMMIT DROP;
        
        -- Select the first total_jobs pending jobs to assign them to the runner
        INSERT INTO selected_jobs(job_id, specification)
        SELECT j.id, j.specification
        FROM api.job AS j
        WHERE status = 'pending'
        LIMIT total_jobs
        FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

        -- Update the selected jobs to set their status to 'running' and assign them to the runner
        UPDATE api.job j
        SET attempted_by = runner_id,
            status = 'running'
        WHERE j.id IN (SELECT s.job_id FROM selected_jobs s);

        -- Return the selected jobs
        RETURN QUERY SELECT s.job_id, s.specification FROM selected_jobs as s;
    END;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You could simplify by doing `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE selected_jobs (job_id integer, specification json)  ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT j.id, j.specification FROM api.job AS j WHERE status = 'pending' LIMIT total_jobs FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that initially, using parentheses, but that didn't work, so I went with a 'noob' way for now